# Question about data from FTSE 100

Tags: stocks

I have the following data from the FTSE 100 list to work with on a math project. However, I'm completely clueless about stocks so I don't actually know what it means...

> 20030101 442.24 442.24 442.24 442.24 0
>
> 20030102 441.79 460.06 428.54 460.06 46075
>
> 20030103 449.78 458.46 438.82 441.33 18386
>
> 20030106 444.98 474.91 420.54 448.64 27361
>
> 20030107 435.39 444.07 429.68 434.48 107910
>
> 20030108 434.02 440.19 426.71 429.68 95434

So, I see that the first column is the date. Are the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th columns the stock price/value at 4 different times of the day? And what is the last column?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the source of your data, it should have mentioned it. Else we can only take assumption as open, high, low, close, last one escapes. me

Comment: As an aside, share prices are listed in pence.

Comment: The last column is probably trade volume for the day.

Answer (score 2):

Open, high, low, close, volume.

The hint is that volume on new years day is 0.

DC's comment is actually a better answer than mine - when given any data set, you should really know the meaning of each cell/number.